# SQL Server query from 2 tables with grouping and average calc

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got 2 tables in SQL Server database:

- table_1: [id], [opt_1], [opt_2], [opt_3], [opt_4]
- table_2: [id], [result]

What I need is query that returns table with grouped records by [opt_1] and [opt_2] like this:

```
[opt_1],
[opt_2],
{count of such records from table_1},
{count of such records from table_2, by [id]},
{average [result] from table_2, by [id]}
```

What is the best way to get it?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`, `JOIN`.  Show what you have tried.

Comment: What did you try up to know? Any query already tried?

Comment: {count of such records from table_1}, {count of such records from table_2, by [id]} these two needs more explanation. What is your actual output that you need. an example or sample will help to understand your exact needs.

Comment: Confirm the relationship between the two tables?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `join` and `group by`;

```
select t1.opt_1,t2.opt_2,count(t1.id),AVG(t2.result) from table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.opt_1,t2.opt_2
```

Comment: t2 declaration missed: `inner join table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id`

Comment: Thats the way I tried to do it myself, but in this case both "counts" outputs the same value. Thats wrong.

Comment: "both "counts" outputs the same value" What would you expect ?